# Programmatically creating a Storyboard in a WPF ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a WPF application that loads `Pages` in a templated `NavigationWindow`. I'd like to implement a slide transition when a new page is loaded and since the window can be resized the target values for the transform need to be determined programatically as far as I am aware.

I tried the following in the `NavigationWindow` code-behind but it has no effect when it fires. The `PageContentContainerTransform` is also being correctly located as determined from the debugger.

```
public void DoTransition()
{
    double targetX = this.ActualWidth;

    this.TransitionStoryboard.Stop();
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Children.Clear();
    IEasingFunction easing = new QuadraticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
    DoubleAnimation translateXAnim = new DoubleAnimation() {
        To = targetX,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
        EasingFunction = easing,
    };

    DependencyObject d = this.Template.FindName("pageContentContainerTransform", this) as DependencyObject;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(translateXAnim, d);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateXAnim, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Children.Add(translateXAnim);
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

The `Template` is a `ControlTemplate` containing the following bit of XAML,

```
...
<ContentPresenter 
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="pageContentContainer"
    MaxHeight="{StaticResource ContentWindowMaxHeight}"
    MaxWidth="{StaticResource ContentWindowMaxWidth}"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="pageContentContainerTransform" X="0" Y="0" />
    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
</ContentPresenter>
...
```

Why is there no effect?

**Update**

The animation works if you animate the element directly without wrapping in a `Storyboard` object. E.g.

```
public void DoTransition()
{
    double targetX = this.ActualWidth;

    this.TransitionStoryboard.Stop();
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Children.Clear();
    IEasingFunction easing = new QuadraticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
    DoubleAnimation translateXAnim = new DoubleAnimation() {
        To = targetX,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
        EasingFunction = easing,
    };

    TranslateTransform t = this.Template.FindName("pageContentContainerTransform", this) as TranslateTransform;
    t.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, translateXAnim);

}
```

However presumably you miss out on some nice control elements for the animations that the Storyboard object provides e.g. managing the animations (Stop, Start etc.). There appears to be possible arguments to `.Begin()` on the storyboard object that are pertinent to use within a Template, however calling with `.Begin(this, this.Template)` also does not do anything.

Comment: you may perhaps create a dependency property and bind your transform to it and animate the property for much easy manipulation. accessing objects inside control or data template is a tricky job. you may also try to find any data error in output window while running the app.

Comment: For some reason I think this would be easier if you used the visual state manager, an example althoug h not exactly what you are looking for is http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Animated-navigation-between-Pages.aspx

Comment: Slide transformations are no easy feat to develop. You're much better off using a pre-existing library like [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end a combination of factors got it to work. First, use `Storyboard.SetTargetName` rather than `Storyboard.SetTarget`. Secondly pass in the template context to the `Begin()` method. E.g.

```
public void DoTransition()
{
    double targetX = this.ActualWidth;

    this.TransitionStoryboard.Stop();
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Children.Clear();
    IEasingFunction easing = new QuadraticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
    DoubleAnimation translateXAnim = new DoubleAnimation() {
        To = targetX,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
        EasingFunction = easing,
    };

    // 1. Refer to the element by Name
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(translateXAnim, "pageContentContainerTransform");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateXAnim, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Children.Add(translateXAnim);
    // 2. Pass in the template context here
    this.TransitionStoryboard.Begin(this, this.Template);    
}
```

I'm not clear why  the `SetTargetProperty` does not work when you consider that `FindName` correctly identified the element within the template, but in any case the above methods works.